# Deploying a nodejs app to the google cloud platform

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I signed up for the free trial of the google cloud platform, and I'm stuck. My application is a node server using express. It needs to connect to a mongodb cluster. I just need to be able to serve a couple of pages. How could I do this using the compute engine. Is there a really simple tutorial to follow to deploy my app? I can't use the app engine because managed vms aren't available in Europe. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying a node.js app to Google Compute Engine really isn't all that different from deploying it on any other Infrastructure as a Service provider.

Try one of the following tutorials:

- https://gun.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-node-js-server-with-example/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04
- https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-deploy-production-best-practice/

You'll need to spin up a Google Compute Engine VM instance, of course, to deploy to.

You can do this using the `gcloud compute instances create` command:

```
gcloud compute instances create --image ubuntu-14-04 --machine-type n1-standard-1 your-instance-name
```

Then, connect via `gcloud compute ssh`:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone [zone you created your instance in] your-instance-name
```

You can also do both of these steps from the [Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Comment: I went to the "cloud launcher" and created a vm with bitnami. How can I tell the server to run my application code?

Comment: That sounds like a Bitnami issue, which is best addressed in another SO question.

Comment: As you can see from https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/nodejs?q=node, Bitnamit provides support for their images via their community site: https://community.bitnami.com/

Comment: @Zachary the first blog is a bit dated and the last one isn't a tutorial, it's a list of suggestions. I went through digitalocean tutorial but the ssh on compute engine is really slow and I'm not familiar with ubuntu commands. Is there a tutorial for setting up a node server using windows operating system vm?

Comment: My hunch is that if ssh to a GCE Linux VM is slow, remote desktop to a GCE Windows VM will be slower, but you're welcome to try. You can look into [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) or [this alternative solution](http://dvisagie.blogspot.com/2013/02/running-nodejs-alongside-iis-on-windows.html).

Comment: @Rockstar5645 — You can use [another Linux distro](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/) if you prefer Debian, CentOS, RedHat or SUSE over Ubuntu. Note that RedHat and SUSE are premium images and carry an additional software license cost. Debian, CentOS, and Ubuntu are free from the software licensing perspective, but note that GCE VM cost still applies in all cases.

Comment: I want to use windows os, how can we install node on the vm?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share one of my deployment experience. I found it's the most easy way in all the tutorials I see.

I use [google cloud launcher](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher) to launch a [Bitnami](https://community.bitnami.com/) VM, MEAN Stack in my case. They also have a node.js solution.

Then you can follow this tutorial [Bitnami Custom Node.js Application](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Custom_Node.js_Application).
Basically five steps :

1. create the basic application directory structure under /opt/bitnami/apps.

   apps/myapp

   |- conf

   |- htdocs

   |- data (optional)
2. put the application code in htdocs folder
3. edit the configuration file
4. start the application

   sudo /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/forever start myapp.js

or if you use express generated project :

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/forever start ./bin/www
```

5. restart the Apache server to refresh new configuration

   sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache